# Maven Plugin for Version Management

Tags: maven

I am looking for a possibility to manage my maven project versions.

I have some maven modules in my maven project and some of these modules are depending on others of these modules.

I want to define the version to work with globally for every module or dependency.

Is this somehow possible?

Something like

```
globalVersion=2.0

<groupId>test</groupId>
<artifactId>test</artifactId>
<version>${globalVersion}</version>
```

But as i said, not in each single pom. I mean globally for all my poms in my maven modules.

Comment: I'd be interested in this also. I do something like this with Maven filtering for other files in my project, not pom files though.

Comment: You could have a parent pom with a `<dependencyManagement>` section where you can define all your version numbers. Then your children only need to reference the parent and the groupId/artifactId. The version will be that defined in the parent.

Comment: nope. this solution isnt working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(I assume you have a parent pom common for all your modules.)

define a property in the parent pom:

```
<properties>
    <globaleVersion>1.0.0</globalVersion>
</properties>
```

And define a [`<dependencyManagement>`](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management) section in the parent pom too:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>test</groupId>
            <artifactId>test</artifactId>
            <version>${globalVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>A</groupId>
            <artifactId>A</artifactId>
            <version>${globalVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
 </dependencyManagement>
```

And in you modules define dependencies without specifying the version (maven will find it from the dependencyManagement section of the parent)

```
     <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>test</groupId>
            <artifactId>test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>A</groupId>
            <artifactId>A</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: thx this helped a lot already.
in the pom of my maven-modules i also have to define the parent-project. is this also working with this definition so that i can just delete the version tag?

Comment: no... sorry you are forced to reference the parent with it's proper version number in the `<parent>` section. (It is required because the `globalVersion` is define in the parent... so it cannot be use to find the parent.)

Comment: ok i see. and your solution isnt working :(

"null (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources:default-resources:process-
  resources)" it says by the packaging tag and "Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version'" is missing by the dependency tag of each module.

Comment: did you define the parent properly? (I'm using this solution in all my project and it works fine)

Comment: as version of my parent pom i use ${globaleVersion} now. i list all my modules under <modules><module>a</module>....</modules> than i did the dependencyManagement section where i defined all my modules with group-, artifactId and with the ${globaleVersion}. in my child-poms now i have no version-tags anymore. no, this is not working. its giving these two errors postet above in each child-pom.

Comment: did you install your modified parent pom in your local repository ? (running `mvn install -N` in the parent pom directory)

Comment: i manage everything in eclipse. 
But when i run mvn install -N, i get a warning: "'version' contains an expression but should be a constant. @ myproject:${globaleVersion} in pom.xml". after that it still not works

Comment: according my experience : never trust eclipse when you do maven setup ! (when I say never it means NEVER). Always use the command line (or any other IDE).

Comment: what's the error ? (the constant inside version tag is just a WARN and shouldn't make your build failing)

Comment: for information, the error is : "dependencies.dependency.version for project is missing". But i found a much easier way. you dont need the dependencyManagement. just use the ${globaleVersion} from your parent-project in each child-project. its working ;)